# Texmaker error: Cannot determine size of graphic

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, texmaker

Hi everyone I hope you are having a good day !
I have a problem with my Latex editor TexMaker when I try to insert an image using this simple code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{image.jpg} 

\end{document}
```

It shows up this error :

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in image.jpg (no BoundingBox).See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \includegraphics[scale=1]{image.jpg}
```

My friend uses the same editor and doesn't have this problem with the same file so I think it's a settings problem

THANK YOU FOR HELP !

Comment: Welcome! It is a bit surprising that the error message mentions `\includegraphics[scale=1]{image.jpg}` while your document has `\includegraphics[scale=1]{nott.PNG} `. Are you sure you are compiling this very document?

Comment: yes I am sorry . it's just a mistake because I changed the image but the problem remain

Comment: It is still surprising because in the document the extension is `.PNG` but in the error message `image.jpg`. In order to debug codes that are run somewhere else it is important to be very precise.

Comment: sorry again I am little nervous I lost concentration . I tried with lots of images so I posted one and the error of one other I will correct that. thanks for your revision.

Comment: What happens if you use `\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-duck}` instead? There might be a chance that the `image.jpg` file has some problem.

Comment: should I use it exactly like this without the extension jpg ?

Comment: no it doesnt work

Comment: I got the exact same error, also in TeXmaker, when I compiled a file using `latex` instead of `pdflatex`; try using the latter and see if this was the issue (as far as I understand, bitmap images don't have the boundingbox parameter within them, but EPS files do, so inserting an EPS and running `latex` *should* do the  trick).

Comment: (1) yes,  you can omit or not the extension of images  (2) Just change  `{image.jpg}` by `{example-image.jpg}`  in your MWE and it should work with ***`pdflatex`***,  but ***NOT***  with `latex`.` The `latex` engine cannot manage JP or PNG images, causing that error.

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo no it doesn't work neither for Latex nor pdflatex

Comment: why when I use Texwork the same file works correctly @Fran

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: @elmrabti The editor is irrelevant, the issue is what program  **you** called from this editor to read your document and produce something. Both texmaker and texworks can execute several programs that **you** must choose accordingly to what you want to produce.

Answer (score 1):

This work perfectly compiled with pdflatex, xelated or lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image.jpg} 
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

But if you try to compile it with `latex`, the result will be:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in example-image.jpg (no Boundi
ngBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image.jpg}

?
```

However, without the `.jpg`  extension, this will work also with the `latex` engine, producing a DVI output.

**Explanation**: `latex` command manage only files with EPS images, but it was forced to use the JPG version. Without the .jpg` extension, the engine is allowed to use the EPS version, thus producing a DVI output.

BTW, the  DVI format is of little use today. Therefore, instead of convert  the JPG image to EPS and then the DVI output to a PDF format, probably you may want just use `pdflatex` and make your life easier.